# Can I update a dictionary outside of context ? (flask, apscheduler)

Tags: python, flask

I want to update a dictionary periodically in flask app.

My code is:

> app.py

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__=='__main__':
  app.dictionary = { ... }
  app.scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
  app.scheduler.add_job('updater:Updater.update', ... )
  app.scheduler.start()
  app.run(...)
```

> updater.py

```
class Updater:
  @classmethod
  def update_dict(cls, old_dic, new_dic):
    old_dic = new_dic  # update

  @classmethod
  def update(cls, old_dic):

    # some business logic ..

    cls.update_dict(old_dic, new_dic)
```

Of course, it works if I manually modify the values ​​inside the dictionary (`old_dic.update( ... )` or `old_dic[..] = ...` ), but it doesn't work if I bind the whole new dictionary (`old_dic = new_dic`).

Is there any way to directly access app.dictionary in Updater?

Thanks!

Comment: No.  You can't rebind names in the caller.  You can only modify the objects you were given.  This is what `update` is for.

Comment: `old_dic.update(new_dic)` should work just fine, is there really any reason you want to avoid it?

Comment: because the update() function does not remove the removed key/value.